# pictures takes too much storage despite saved on cloud

Tags: insufficient-memory, cache, google-plus-photos

I have a storage problem and that is because my pictures and videos takes too much space.
The thing is that all my pictures and videos are automatically loaded to Google plus. so why do they also take such a large storage on my device (Nexus 4)?
I want to enjoy both words: low storage and access to all my images and I am willing to pay by waiting for images to download if it is not viewed often (caching?). 
what am I missing?

Comment: I don't think Google+ deletes the local copy when it uploads. The photos are probably still on your device, in addition to being backed up on Google+. That's the way most other services work, certainly (Dropbox behaves like this).

Comment: so what do I do?

Comment: Delete the local copies if you don't need them?

Comment: Aren't the pictures in sync? that is, deleting the picture from the phone will also deletes it from google plus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

Bottom line here is android users must manage their own pictures and videos storage.

It is important to understand that the "Gallery" application (and probably the new alternative "Photos") is not synced to Google Plus, they are merely backuped; This means that Gallery does not deletes (leave a thumbnail) least recent used pictures to save space (as i mistakenly assumed).

I, for one, will be using Google plus application from now on to be able to access all my pictures and videos and will be deleting images as soon as they are backuped.